# How to remove shortcut and wscript.exe viruses

Tags: windows-7

I came across to some solutions on the internet and one of them says that we should delete wscript to prevent to create the shortcut virus on flash disk and here is steps to do that :

1. takeown /f C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe
2. cacls C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe /G GeekGates:F (you replace GeekGates  with name of user )
3. attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:*.*

something like that my question should do that to delete wscript is it virus and could someone elaborate the steps for that Thank you

Comment: What virus are you talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: @Ramhound No it's not, I already saw that link

Comment: Have you tried out my answer?

Answer (score 3):

`wscript.exe` is **not** a virus, and removing it is useless, because of `cscript.exe`, which is a `wscript.exe` alternative. What you can do is remove any file that cause it to trigger.

But if you *really* want to delete that file, then:

1. Boot to safe mode
2. Type these commands in an elevated command prompt:

   ```
   cd %SystemRoot%\System32
   takeown /f wscript.exe
   icacls /grant Administrators:F
   del wscript.exe /f
   ```

See also: [wscript | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wscript), [Windows Script Host - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)

Comment: I don't think that's an answer to OP's question...

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 I edited my answer to delete wscript.exe

Comment: It's not very in-depth... Safe Mode will **NOT** make a difference. The problem is in File Ownership.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 It's in-depth now...